# Why does Perl think that a non-existent multi-level hash element is there?

Tags: perl, hash, zero

Sorry, this seems like such a basic question but I still don't understand. If I have a hash, for example:

```
my %md_hash = ();
$md_hash{'top'}{'primary'}{'secondary'} = 0;
```

How come this is true?

```
if ($md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'} == 0) {
    print "I'm true even though I'm not in that hash\n";
}
```

There is no "foobar" level in the hash so shouldn't that result in false?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a search on "Perl autovivification".

The hash values "spring into existence" when you first access them.  In this case, the value is `undef`, which when interpreted as a number is zero.

To test for existence of a hash value without auto-vivifying it, use the `exists` operator:

```
if (exists $md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'}
    && $md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'} == 0) {
    print "I exist and I am zero\n";
}
```

Note that this will still auto-vivify `$md_hash{'top'}` and
`$md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}` (i.e. the sub-hashes).

[edit]

As tchrist points out in a comment, it is poor style to compare `undef` against anything.  So a better way to write this code would be:

```
if (defined $md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'}
    && $md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'} == 0) {
    print "I exist and I am zero\n";
}
```

(Although this will now auto-vivify all three levels of the nested hash, setting the lowest level to `undef`'.)

Comment: Awesome!! Your example fixed my problem and your advise led me to http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Autovivification, now I know!! Thanks!

Comment: @Analog: But that is not the right answer. The right answer is not to apply numeric equality tests against undefined values.

Comment: @tchrist:  So every statement I made was 100% correct, and I solved the OP's problem, but because I violated your personal sense of style you downvoted my answer.  Have I got that right?  Classy!

Comment: @Nemo: No: the problem is that you didn’t answer the question, which was why he shouldn’t get false when testing an undefined value against numeric zero. The answer is that he always should, since `undef` is numeric zero, and therefore to give anything but true on that test would be wrong. I’ll remove the downvote with a better edit, but you still don’t get an upvote.

Comment: @tchrist:  Well, I would never demand an upvote...  But I did write, from the beginning, "In this case, the value is `undef`, which when interpreted as a number is zero".  So I am not sure what you mean about my not answering his question.

Comment: please read my answer and see if it helps you understand autovivification.  a nonexistent hash value yielding undef doesn't have much to do with autovivification, nor are all three levels autovivified.

Answer (score 7):

You are testing an undefined value for numeric zero.  Of course you get a true result!  What were you expecting?

You should also get a warning under `use warnings`.  Why didn’t you?

If you do not start a program with:

```
use v5.12;  # or whatever it is you are using
use strict;
use warnings;
```

you really shouldn’t even bother. :)

---

## EDIT

> NB: I am only clarifying for correctness, because the comment lines are not good for that. I really could not possibly care one whingeing whit less about the reputation points. I just want people to understand.

Even under the CPAN `autovivification` module, nothing changes.  Witness:

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
no  autovivification;

my %md_hash = ();

$md_hash{top}{primary}{secondary} = 0;

if ($md_hash{top}{foobar}{secondary} == 0) {
    say "yup, that was zero.";
}
```

When run, that says:

```
$ perl /tmp/demo
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at /tmp/demo line 10.
yup, that was zero.
```

The test is the `==` operator.  Its RHS is `0`.  Its LHS is `undef` **irrespective of autovivification**. Since `undef` is numerically `0`, that means that both LHS and RHS contain `0`, which the `==` correctly identifies as holding the same number.

Autovivification is not the issue here, as ysth correctly observes when he writes that “This isn’t a multidimensional hash specific question.”  All that matters is what you pass to `==`.  And `undef` is numerically `0`.

You can stop autoviv if you really, really want to — by using the CPAN pragma. But you will not ever manage to change what happens here by suppressing autoviv. That shows that it is not an autoviv matter at all, just an `undef` one.

Now, you *will* get “extra” keys when you do this, since the undefined lvalue will get filled in on the way through the dereference chain.  These are neccesarily all the same:

```
$md_hash{top}{foobar}{secondary}            # implicit arrow for infix deref
$md_hash{top}->{foobar}->{secondary}        # explicit arrow for infix deref
${ ${ $md_hash{top} }{foobar} }{secondary}  # explicit prefix deref
```

Whenever you deref an lvaluable `undef` in Perl, that storage location *always* gets filled in with the proper sort of reference to a newly allocated anonymous referent of the proper type.  In short, **it autovivs**.

And *that* you can stop either by suppressing or else by sidestepping the autoviv. However, denying the autoviv is not the same as sidestepping it, because you just change what sort of thing gets returned. The overall expession is still fully evaluated: **there is no automatic short-circuiting** just because you suppress autoviv. That’s because autoviv is not the problem (and if it were not there, you would be really annoyed: trust me).

If you want short-circuiting, you have to write that yourself.  I never seem to need to myself. In Perl, that is. On the other hand,  C programmers are quite accustomed to writing

```
 if (p && p->whatever) { ... }
```

And so you can do that, too, if you want to.  However, it is pretty rare in my own experience. You almost have to bend over wrongwards in Perl for that ever to make a difference, as it is quite easy to arrange for your code *not* to change how it acts if there are empty levels.

Comment: re `always`, not so.  and it's hard to state the general rule; things autovivify when it isn't irksome for them to do so, which is more or less when a modifying type of operation takes place.  Compare `my $foo; 1 if @$foo; print $foo` to `my $foo; undef @$foo; print $foo`.

Comment: If this is different than you remember, it may be because you and Larry left p5p for so many years, resulting in some decisions being made that you may have disagreed with had you been around (case in point, the removal of `package;`)

Comment: @ysth: I never left p5p. I merely skipped reading it for several years. I still have the whole thing in my mail partition. :)

Comment: in any case, it's nice to have you back (though it is partition-filler for me too more often than not)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a multidimensional hash specific question.

It works the same with

```
my %foo;
if ( $foo{'bar'} == 0 ) {
    print "I'm true even though I'm not in that hash\n";
}
```

`$foo{'bar'}` is undef, which compares true to 0, albeit with a warning if you have warnings enabled as you should.

There is an additional side effect in your case; when you say

```
my %md_hash = ();
$md_hash{'top'}{'primary'}{'secondary'} = 0;

if ( $md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}{'secondary'} == 0 ) {
    print "I'm true even though I'm not in that hash\n";
}
```

`$md_hash{'top'}` returns a hash reference, and the 'foobar' key is looked for in that hash.  Because of the `{'secondary'}`, that 'foobar' element lookup is in hash-dereference context.  This makes `$md_hash{'top'}{'foobar'}` "autovivify" a hash reference as the value of the 'foobar' key, leaving you with this structure:

```
my %md_hash = (
    'top' => {
        'primary' => {
            'secondary' => 0,
        },
        'foobar' => {},
    },
);
```

The autovivification pragma can be used to disable this behavior.  People sometimes assert that exists() has some effect on autovifification, but this is not true.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This is not an autoviv issue. It is an “I forgot to `use warnings`” problem. I have *never* had autoviv be a problem, but I have often had `undef` be a problem.  Autoviv never caused a bug in my code, ever. Only misusing definite tests on indefinite contents has.

Comment: Sigh, you know I did and I never even noticed the "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string", I was printing out soo much other crap. Major fail on my part.